# How to modify each entry in the list by converting it to a numeric value?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write function called toNumbers based on the following specifications:

-toNumbers modifies each entry in the list by converting it to a numeric value.
-Call toNumbers function to convert each entry in the list to numeric form.
- Display the original and converted lists in your main function, not in toNumbers

```
for i in (toNumbers(myList)):
myList[i] = myList [i] * (1+rate)

def main():
myList = ['5','-2','3.5','-4.5']
print(myList)

main()
```

However, I'm not sure what function to use in order to modify my list.
Thanks! 
(I'm using Python 3.5)

Comment: `[int(item) for item in myList]`? or same thing with `float`.

Comment: If your specs allow it, just call `float` on each item....

Comment: `for i in range(len(myList)): myList[i] = float(myList[i]) * (1+rate)`

Answer (score 0):

```
rate = 0.5
input_list = ['5','-2','3.5','-4.5']
output_list = [float(item)*(1+rate) for item in input_list]
print(output_list)
```

Comment: why do you multiply each item by 1.5 ?

Comment: Because in the original code in the question above the person asking the question multiplied each number by (1+rate). He didn't specify what that rate is but I assumed he would want to. I just chose 0.5 for the rate for no reason whatsoever, but whatever that rate should be the code above allows you to set it explicitly.

Comment: In other words, if I understand what he's try to do, he starts with a list of numbers that happen to be formatted as Python strings and he wants to finish with a list of numbers where each number is the original number multiplied by one plus some rate. To get from A to B, you need to specify the rate, convert each string in the list to a Python float and multiple by one plus the rate.

Answer (score 0):

Your main will look like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    new_list = [toNumbers(num) for num in myList]
    print(new_list, myList)
```

it creates *new_list* by calling *toNumbers* on each value in the list, than returns a list of those values

then it prints both lists all in *main*